# One rails application, two domains, different session for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, session-cookies

I have one application, with two different domains. They cross in User model. I have Devise for sign in/out. How to make session for each domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT***

You need to identify by url or identify with select with domain where you are.

example identifying by domain. However you will need adapt it to your environment

`http://www.domain1.com`

`rake g model Domain name:string, user:belongs_to

#domain.rb

```
Class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs :user
end
```

#user.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :domains
end
```

in your rails console

```
 User.find(1).domains.create(name:'www.domain1.com')
 User.find(1).domains.create(name:'www.domain2.com')
```

#application_controller.rb  #EDITED

```
helper_method :current_domain

def current_domain
  domain = request.host
  Domain.find_by_name(domain)
end
```

you need modify you new in sessions controller

#app/views/sessions/new.html.slim

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user, :domain_id, value: current_domain.try(:id)
```

in your config/initializer/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :domain_id ]
```

#app/models/user.rb

```
devise authentication_keys: {email:true, login:false, domain_id:true}

def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions) 
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  domain_id = conditions.delete(:domain_id)
  where(conditions).joins(:domains).where('domains.id = :value', {:value => domain_id }).first
end
```

Comment: users are shared between domains

Comment: `application_controller.rb` instead  `application.rb`

Comment: I look at the code twice and I think this will not resolve my problem. I want to make session from request.host and don't create records for each user -domain

Comment: But how do you expect the `Devise` know which the domain is that user has associate in your application? You need inform the devise which the user has the domain xxx.com to authenticate.

Comment: I think it should use request.host/domain to create session cookie and to find it for destroy

Comment: How `domain_id` appears for all current users in db and for new users?

Comment: And when I try to sign_out — i get `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

Comment: @stereodenis take way from a computer. I will answer asap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121463/discussion-between-breno-perucchi-and-stereodenis).

Comment: I get this cause I have no `csrf_meta_tags`. When I add it — all start works without your solution)